# MySQL ordering a field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table called chapters as shown below:

The field `chapter_number` is used to order chapters of a story.

The problem I am facing is if a user deletes a chapter then the ordering would somehow need to be updated.

I though about populating the `chapter_number` field with the value of the previous row plus 1.

So if I deleted a row then that would still keep linear ordering of my rows.

Is this a good way to go about it?

If so, how would I access the value of the previous row in PHP?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, that `chapter_number` is used for the ordering.

In MySQL, you can update a table using `order by` and variables.  If you have an ordering in place and delete a row, then the following will re-number the chapters consecutively:

```
update chapters
    set chapter_number = (@o := coalesce(@o, 0) + 1)
    order by chapter_number;
```

Comment: `chapter_id` is not actually used for ordering but to uniquely identify a record (as its the primary key), I have used `chapter_number` for the ordering, is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: @user3574492 . . . That is fine.  I missed that (now obvious) second sentence in the question.

Comment: when Inserting a new record how would I say `chapter_number` of previous row + 1?

Comment: @user3574492 . . . That is another question and should be asked as a question, not in a comment.

Comment: but it's related to this question and would be better if made clear on this post rather than starting a new one

Answer (score 0):

as long as rows are just deleted and you are using *chapter_number* just for sorting and not for display, then you would not have to renumber the *chapter_number* field, since the desired order would still stay preserved. only in case of insertion you would query the highest *chapter_number* before inserting.

a typical method would actually be totally renumbering the chapter_number field:

```
SET @x = 0;
UPDATE chapters SET chapter_number = (@x:=@x+1) ORDER BY chapter_number;
```

in PHP you would have to split this in two queries, but variables will stay valid since you are working on same connection which is persistent during page processing.

```
mysql_query("SET @x = 0");
mysql_query("UPDATE chapters SET chapter_number = (@x:=@x+1) ORDER BY chapter_number");
```

you can find a very detailed description of this concept in this older mysql question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39278/update-column-based-on-the-sort-order-of-another-query)